# Pass ActionForm data in JQuery.ajax() using form id

Tags: jquery, struts

Is there a way where I can pass all the form data to a struts 1 action using JQuery.ajax().
I don't want to pass the individual values and without using $("#formId").serailize()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/)

You can call `$("#formId").ajaxSubmit();` to do what you want.